# How to compare value in adjacent cell in SUMIF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Assuming the following dataset:

```
A   B   C
40  8   5
40  40  10
```

How do I conditionally sum column C if A = B? I tried the following but `ROW()` is based on the row the formula is in, not the row being evaluated.

```
=SUMIF(A1:C2,INDIRECT("B"&ROW()),C1:C2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [SumProduct](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753E75-9F68-4874-94AC-4D2145A2FD2E) formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$2=$B$1:$B$2),$C$1:$C$2)
```

Using your example the above formula should give 10.

Comment: Mcalex, This Formula need a little correction, before $C$1 in place of  ' ,  '   (Comma) ' * ' sign is required.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest you a different Formula. Which meets your Query **How do I conditionally sum column C if A = B**.*

Check the Screen Shot below.*

[image]

The Formula is,

```
{=SUM(C2:C3)*(--(A2:A3=B2:B3))}
```

**NB:** It's an Array Formula so finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

*Hope this help you.*